# how to use range checker attribute if i want the minimum value to be based of the model's property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this part on my application:[image]

I have this off my model:

```
[Range(0,40)]
public int max { get; set; }
```

What i want to happen is, i want to restrict my user from setting the max number of students lesser than the current number of enrolled(it varies since this is an edit action).

Do i need to use `Remote` Attribute for this case or are there any other way around? i want to set the minimum to be the based from this model's property:

```
 public int enroll { get; set; }    current number of enrolled students
```

Comment: A `[Remote]` attribute wont help if your editing both values in the view. Look at using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[LessThan]` or similar validation attribute

Comment: Actually, the current student enrolled can't be edited since it's based off the number of enrolled students(unless i removed someone or someone dropped). I see, i wish i knew that sooner because i had to manually code and compare my dates. thank you, let me try it.